# Filter http://magento.stackexchange.com user questions

Tags: discussion, users

Is it possible to filter http://magento.stackexchange.com questions, so I won't see any questions from certain users?

For instance, users who constantly edit the original question, so posting answers is a total waste of time

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible out of the box, but you can add this script to GreaseMonkey: [Ignore Users Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3360/224252)